# Overriding CompareTo when there are multiple ways to compare two objects of the same type?

Tags: vb.net

What's a sound approach to override the `CompareTo()` method in a custom class with multiple approaches to comparing the data contained in the class?  I'm attempting to implement `IComparable(Of T)` just so I have a few of the baseline interfaces implemented.  Not planning on doing any sorting yet, but this will save me down the road if I need to.

Reading MSDN states mostly that we have to return 0 if the objects are equal, -1 if obj1 is less than obj2, or 1 is obj1 is greater than obj2.  But that's rather simplistic.

Consider an IPv4 address (which is what I'm implementing in my class).  There's two main numbers to consider -- the IP address itself, and the CIDR.  An IPv4 address by itself is assumed to have a CIDR of /32, so in that case, in a `CompareTo` method, I can just compare the addresses directly to determine if one is greater or less than the other.  But when the CIDR's are different, then things get tricky.

Assume obj1 is `10.0.0.0/8` and obj2 is `192.168.75.0/24`.  I could compare these two addresses a number of ways.  I could just ignore the CIDR, and still regard as obj2 as being greater than obj1.  I could compare them based on their CIDR, which would be comparing the size of the network (and a /8 will trump a /24 quite easily).  I could compare them on both their numerical address AND their CIDR, on the off chance obj2 was actually an address *inside* the network defined by obj1.

What's the kind of approach used to handle situations like this?  Can I define two `CompareTo` methods, overloaded, such that one would evaluate one address relative to another address, and the second would evaluate the size of the overall network?  How would the .NET framework be told which one to use depending on how one might want to sort an array?  Or do some other function that relies on `CompareTo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CompareTo, you should use a comparison that represents the default, normal sort order for a particular type. For example, in the example you gave, I would probably expect it to sort on the address first, then on the subnet size.

But for the case where there is no obvious "default" sort order, or when there are multiple ways to compare (such as case sensitive or not when comparing strings) the recommended approach is to use an `IComparer<T>`. This would be a separate object that is able to compare two instances of your type. For example, a AddressComparer or SubnetComparer. You could even make them static properties of a class which is what StringComparer does.

Just about all methods that take IComparable types should also have an overload that allows you to specify an IComparer to use instead. You don't have to implement both, but if it makes sense, do it. That way you can specify a particular comparer when needed or use the default built-in IComparable logic of your type.

Comment: +1. Fun fact: The word "comparer", used in the .NET framework, isn't even a real word... it should've been called "comparator".

Comment: They could have called it ICanCompareStuff I suppose :)

Comment: @Lambert: [http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparer). It's also listed as a related noun form of the word compare on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compare).

Comment: @Cody: I think the word only came into existence because they started using it... just take a look and compare the results in Google for `define: comparer` and `define: comparator`.

Comment: @Josh: Hmm, those are some very good points -- and they explain StringComparer.  I was looking at that class earlier in Reflector and wondering what it is for.  Still, for IP Addresses, it bugs me.  Maybe I'll post a question to ServerFault to get IP address comparison cleared up and figure about implementation based on anything they can provide.

Comment: How does one do them as static/shared classes, off hand?  I've looked at StringComparer in Reflector, but it's not "clicking" how exactly they're doing it there.

Comment: You could make a class called IPAddressComparer that has properties that determine whether it sorts IP or subnet first. Then have static properties like: `class IPComparer { public static IPComparer IPFirst {get; private set; } public static IPComparer SubnetFirst {get; private set; } }`

Comment: Well, ServerFault was a waste of time.  They closed my question on IP address sorting because a few tools couldn't read.  Pft.

Comment: That is a common problem with Stack Exchange sites unfortunately. I expect it will only get worse with the arrival of programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: @Josh: Yeah, I'm still fairly new here.  Way better than Experts Exchange (only because it's free here).  Low reputation means I brought a toothpick to a gun fight over there.  I'll revisit the question in a few months when I've built my rep up some more.  I've got to test someone's answer to another one of my questions on SO first, then I'll look at your answer here.  Thanks!

Comment: Well to your original point, I think it makes far more sense to compare two IP blocks based on the start address rather than the subnet size.